# How to correctly resize images to retain quality in Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, image, phaser-framework

I am making a game in Phaser 3. I have downloaded high quality (1100x1000px) images from the internet to use. But whenever I shrink them (to roughly 80x70px) they lose quality (either become pixelated or have a weird appearance). How do I correctly re-size the images to retain quality?

I re-sized the image using image.setDisplaySize() but the image looked weird. I am not sure why but the image contrasting has changed.
Exact Code-

```
gameState.team_player_icon = gameState.screen_team_group.create(100, 130, (gameState.all_player_team[0].skin))

gameState.scale_size = gameState.team_player_icon.displayHeight/70
gameState.team_player_icon.setDisplaySize(gameState.team_player_icon.displayWidth/gameState.scale_size, 70)
```

I have already resized using canvas in paint editor 3 and the image looked fine but I want to know how to do it in Phaser 3 to save having to re-edit all the images for my game. Here it is below-

Phaser 3 image here-

[image]

Canvas Edited here-

[image]

In case it is not clear I want the image to look like the bottom image but using phaser 3. Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 9):

```js
var config = {
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  loader: {
    baseURL: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nazimboudeffa/assets/master/',
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
  },
  pixelArt: true,//here
  //antialias: false,
  scene: {
    preload: preload,
    create: create
  }
};


var game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload ()
{
    this.load.image('alien', 'sprites/phaser-alien.png');
}

function create ()
{
    sprite = this.add.image(50, 50, 'alien');

    sprite.setScale(2);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.17.0/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried using pixelArt:true and antialias:false but the images remained distorted. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Maybe it's because you use `setDisplaySize(w,h)` with w and h diffrent which will distord the image like in this example https://jsfiddle.net/nazimboudeffa/xtovdh37/

Comment: I have used gameState.scale_size to ensure the ratio of width to height remains the same. The problem I am encountering is more with the colours then the size of the image.

Comment: Okey so I think that the scaling problem is fixed, right ? for the colors you should ask another question

Comment: Perhaps my question wasn't clear. The bottom image was edited using Paint Editor 3 (by modifying the original image). The image looked correct and sized correctly but this is impractical to manually resize all the images used in my game. Instead I resized the image within Phaser 3 itself (the top image) but the colours are distorted.I would like to know why the colours are distorted and how to fix the colour distortion (so the image looks like the bottom image). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `scale` attribute of the image:

```js
const config = {
  type: Phaser.AUTO,
  width: 640,
  height: 480,
  loader: {
    baseURL: 'https://i.ibb.co/t8p496v/',
    crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
  },
  scene: {
    preload: preload,
    create: create
  }
};

const game = new Phaser.Game(config);

function preload() {
  this.load.image('mario', 'mario.png');
}

function create() {
  const mario = this.add.image(320, 240, 'mario');
  mario.scale = 0.5; // Resize the image
}
```

```css
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser/3.24.1/phaser.min.js"></script>
```

The image that appears in the center of the screen is half of its original size.

If you don't want that Phaser.js console message to block the view in the example, don't worry! You can find a JSFiddle version [here](https://jsfiddle.net/BlueWolf153622/c2veL1aw/).